# MySQL consult in QProgressBar

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt

Anyone know how I can show thee Progress of inserting data into a mysql database using QSqlDatabase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a `QProgressBar` you would have to assign some sort of value to the data you are inserting into the Database, so as long as you know what the amount of data is you could do:

```
qProgressBar.setRange(0, 100);
```

and when you are calculating the percentage of the data completed all you will have to do is:

```
pctValue = abs(dataInserted*100/dataSize);
qProgressBar.setValue(pctValue);
```

Syntax notwithstanding but you get the general idea.